# Como convertir un numero a una fecha en Python

Tags: python, django

Buen día
tengo un numero x por ejemplo el 3
lo que quiero hacer es convertir ese numero 3 para que se convierta en 3 horas, estoy haciendo una agenda de citas por lo que tengo una hora de inicio y una hora de fin pero la hora de fin se pone automáticamente

así que si la cita empieza a las 3:00 PM y la cita tiene una duración de 3 horas, tengo que generar la hora de fin que seria 6:00 PM

intente esto

```
    duracion=request.session["duracion"]
    duracion=str(duracion)
    duracion=datetime.strptime(duracion, "%H:%M")
    duracion=duracion.strftime("%H:%M")
```

pero salió esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar, ya que por ese error veo que tengo un problema en la lógica que estoy pensando implementar

Answer (score 1):

La librería `datetime` proporciona el objeto `timedelta` para este tipo de operaciones. Además puedes sumar entre sí una fecha con un timedelta para obtener otra fecha, que es justo lo que necesitas.

Un ejemplo sencillo sería:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

inicio = datetime.now()
duracion = timedelta(hours=3)
fin = inicio + duracion
print("Inicio: ", inicio)
print("Fin: ", fin)
```

Al ejecutarlo me sale lo siguiente ("Inicio" es la fecha y hora en que lo ejecuté y "Fin", como ves, sale tres horas después):

```
Inicio:  2023-02-03 22:14:13.176004
Fin:  2023-02-04 01:14:13.176004
```

Creo que puedes adaptar este ejemplo sin problema a tu caso. Ten en cuenta que la `duracion` que recibirás en tu servidor web vendrá en forma de cadena, por lo que tendrás que hacer probablemente algo como:

```
horas = request.session["duracion"]
duracion = timedelta(hours=horas)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Intenta lo siguiente:**

1. Usa la librería de `time` y crea una función que puedas utilizar en cualquier momento para convertir horas a segundos.

```
import time 
def convertSeconds(hour):
   return hour * 60 * 60
```

2. Luego en tu conversión usa lo siguiente, y agregas los segundos al método `time.strftime` para obtener un formato '03:00:00' (hh:mm:ss):

```
duracion = 3
StartHour = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(convertSeconds(duracion))) 
EndHour = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(convertSeconds(duracion + 3)))
```

1. Salida:

```
print(StartHour)
print(EndHour)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]